# HTML/Javascript Overlaying Images on Region Mouseovers

Tags: javascript, html, image, dictionary, mouseover

So I have an image on a page and an imagemap corresponding to that image, then I also have two corresponding images, each the same size as the first (mostly transparent) that I want to overlay onto that image when a certain region of the imagemap is moused over. How would I go about doing that, is this something I can accomplish with CSS or will I need javascript for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do need Javascript as not all browsers support css `hover` psuedo-class on elements other than `<a>`. You should be able to do it with minimal Javascript. See the `<map>` tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

For example, if you want mousing over the 100 by 100 pixel square in the top left of your image (image1.png) to enable the overlay image (image2.png):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function area1_mouseover() {
        document.getElementById('image2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    function area1_mouseout() {
        document.getElementById('image2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
<img src="image2.png" id="image2" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 2;" usemap="#my_map" />
<img src="image1.png" id="image1" usemap="#my_map" />
<map name="my_map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" onmouseover="area1_mouseover();" onmouseout="area1_mouseout();" />
</map>
```

Edit: applying the map to all the images should solve that problem since they are all the same size.

Comment: The problem I have now is that the images flash in and out I assume because they are being put over the image map?